# How to make div ellipsis with multiple paragraphs inside it?

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

```
<div>
 <p>This is a sample text.</p>
 <p>This is a 2nd sample text. existing inside a paragraph. I want to make this ellipsis to avoid overflow text.</p>
 <p>This is a last paragraph which is not going to display as 3 lines are already displayed</p>
</div>
```

> required output -

```
This is a sample text.
This is a 2nd sample text. existing 
inside a paragraph. I want to make...
```

I want to make text inside div ellipsis with 3 lines by considering all paragraphs as a single text.
How can I achieve this??

> I have tried following one -

```css
div{
 width: 200px;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: initial;
 display: -webkit-box;
 -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <p>This is a sample text.</p>
 <p>This is a 2nd sample text. existing inside a paragraph. I want to make this ellipsis to avoid overflow text.</p>
 <p>This is a last paragraph which is not going to display as 3 lines are already displayed</p>
</div>
```

But it not working properly as expected if there is multiple paragraph inside div.

Comment: So basically if enough space is, there should be two lines and when there is less space it should break down to two lines? Shouldn't this be the default behaviour?

Comment: I think he is saying that there is two paragraphs but want that should be 3 lines to show somewhere and 3rd line should be ellipsis

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider `display:contents;` on the p elements combined with a pseudo element trick to keep the separation between the p

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: initial;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

div p {
  display: contents;
}

p:after {
  content: "\A";
  white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is a sample text.</p>
  <p>This is a 2nd sample text. existing inside a paragraph. I want to make this ellipsis to avoid overflow text.</p>
  <p>This is a last paragraph which is not going to display as 3 lines are already displayed</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thank you bro. that's working fine but It directly combining all paragraphs together. but I also want to maintain next line functionality of paragraph. can you have any solution for this??

Comment: @OmkarPatil will think about a solution

Comment: @TemaniAfif try adding another `p` text to the div and it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/x9e4tnsa/

Comment: Ya but it taking one extra line.

Comment: @OmkarPatil check again the update, I thought you want a separation

Comment: Furthermore, you can apply `display: block` to the pseudo-element to let it take 1 extra line of space.

Comment: @SigurdMazanti this will generate 6 lines in total and won't be good in this case because the last line of text will be hidden

Comment: @TemaniAfif You can just modify `-webkit-line-clamp: 3` to 6, no? [In my case it worked perfectly](https://gyazo.com/40cb0879000080d954d38a0d0466eca3) using `-webkit-line-clamp: 6`

Comment: @SigurdMazanti but why we should do this? If you want to control the space between the lines, adjust `line-height` on the div element.

Comment: Because you might want to add whitespace between each `<p>`-element, much like hitting `enter` in any WYSIWYG-editor. `line-height` would affect all lines of text, not just the spacing between the `<p>`-elements

Answer (score 0):

Using `clamp` for **multiline**

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/8r67hpw2/) to play-around.

```css
.MainDiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.MainDiv p {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainDiv">
  <p>This is a sample text.</p>
  <p>This is a 2nd sample text. existing inside a paragraph. I want to make this ellipsis to avoid overflow text.</p>
</div>
```

You can do something like this for **single line**

```css
.MainDiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}

p {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainDiv">
  <p>This is a sample text.</p>
  <p>This is a 2nd sample text. existing inside a paragraph. I want to make this ellipsis to avoid overflow text.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please review my question again

Comment: actually I'm getting this paragraphs from database as text and appending it in div. so I can't decide which text I've to consider what to hide as there is multiple paragraphs.

Comment: The code I written for all `p` so even it is dynamic value you will have `ellipse` on 3rd line which is your requirement, you can test that as well. here is the fiddle if you want to take a look : https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/8r67hpw2/

Comment: In your answer, that is the actual issue I'm facing as it considering this css for paragraphs individually and showing 3 lines of all paragraphs with ellipsis if text overflows.but I want to consider all paragraphs together for ellipsis as there in my question.

Comment: so what is it you want then, this should happen on `div`?

Comment: ya.. I want to apply it on div.